# ttyACM* ports on TS-7500 board running Debian

Tags: kernel, tty

When I connect my Arduino Mini to my TS-7500 board running Debian (*Linux ts7500 2.6.24.4*), it doesn't show up as a ACM port.

**dmesg** gives the following output

`[14090.3000] usb 2-1: new full speed USB device using str8100-ohci and address 6`
`[14090.4900] usb 2-1: configuration #1 chosen from 1 choice`

I have read [here](http://tech.dir.groups.yahoo.com/group/ts-7000/message/21633) that I have to recompile the kernel. If so suggest some links, or else how do I tackle this problem ?

**EDIT** : After running `modprobe cdc_acm`, dmesg shows the  following output,

```
usbcore: registered new interface driver cdc_acm
cdc_acm: v0.26:USB Abstract Control Model driver for USB modems and ISDN adapters
```

but still doesn't assign any port (for eg. **ttyACM0**) in /dev. What am I missing ?

Comment: @Flimzy, my question is how to make ACM ports detectable on TS-7500 board. If I have to recompile kernel, yes, I was asking for some links. Else, if there was another way to tackle the problem, do share the same.

Answer (score 1):

Try to modprobe **ehci-hcd** or **ohci-hcd** and **uhci-hcd**. You have to make sure, that support for those USB features is compiled in kernel.

How to compile kernel is described here [TS-7500 Kernel_Compile_Guide](http://wiki.embeddedarm.com/wiki/TS-7500#Kernel_Compile_Guide). It's working well.